# jpaRepository Distinct method not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to find the unique employees from my table i am using JPArepository

```
public List<String> findDistinctempName();
```

I am getting server start exception as

```
No property findDistinctempName found for type Employee !

at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:79) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:335) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:311) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:274) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:245) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:247) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:398) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:378) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:70) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
... 52 common frames omitted
```

can any one suggest me to find the unique rows of a table ,having distinct empName and mobile number

Comment: `findDistinctByEmpName`.

Comment: I think that the column in the database is empname, so I think you should have E instead of e like that : `public List<String> findDistinctByEmpname();`

Comment: @M.Deinum if findDistinctByEmpName i should provide EmpName as input ryt ,i am not passing any input i just want distinct rows in DB with empName

Comment: That is not how the `findBy` queries work. You will have to write a custom query for that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to camelize your method name as well as separate predicates with `by`

```
findDistinctByEmpName();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get distinct records with findBy...you need to create custom query to get the desire result. You can get the unique records by using group by. Please find the repository code below to get the All Cars with group by name and id.

```
    public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {

        @Query("select car from Car car group by car.name,car.id")
        List<Car> findDistinctByName();

    }


    @Entity
    public class Car {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "car_id")
        int car_id;
        String name;

    }
```